# proving a subset of $[0,1]$ is compact and has measure zero.

Tags: measure-theory, compactness, cantor-set

Let $X$ be the set of all numbers in $[0,1]$ which admit a binary representation $0.c_1c_2c_3...$ such that for every natural number $n$:
$c_n=0$ or $c_{n+1}=0$. Prove $X$ is compact and it has measure zero.

I know that this looks like the Cantor set but I cannot express $X$ as intersection of nested closed sets.